# Storing the first 4 characters of a filename into a variable

Tags: bash

This follwing code is part of a script I am writing. Now, for the purposes of this script, I am assuming there is only 1 file in ./src, so this loop should only execute once. Now, in the loop somewhere, I want to take the first 4 characters of $f (the filename) and store it in another variable. I know there is the cut command but I'm not sure if or how that would be used here because I thought cut was used for contents of files, not the files themselves.

```
for f in `ls ./src`
do
    echo $f
    cd tmp
    f="../src/$f"
    sh "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

> **Substring Extraction**
>
> `${string:position}`
> Extracts substring from $string at $position.
>
> If the $string parameter is "*" or "@", then this extracts the positional parameters, [1] starting at $position.
>
> `${string:position:length}`
> Extracts $length characters of substring from $string at $position.

**Example**

```
shortName=${f:0:4}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

You can use pure bash way:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

i.e. to get first chars of `$HOME` variable:

```
echo ${HOME:0:4}
```

btw your script is also faulty (never parse ls output). It should be like this:

```
for f in ./src/*
do
    echo $f
    cd tmp
    f="../src/$f"
    first4=${f:0:4}
    sh "$f"
done
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting a "bad substitution" error. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Pls post your latest script in your question and I can debug that.

Comment: Actually I just googled it and it seems to be because I was using sh when I should have used bash. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yes use bash it is much superior to sh.

Comment: It is totally your choice but any particular reason why you removed accepted mark from this answer which I wrote before the other one.